# AS3 Event Listener for MovieClip alteration

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-listener

I wonder if it's possible to add an Event Listener to a MovieClip that fires everytime a child is added to it or removed from it.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance,

Matteo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override addChild / addChildAt and removeChild / removeChildAt functions and dispatch any event You want :

```
public override function addChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject {
    dispatchEvent(new Event("newChild"));
    return super.addChild(child);
}
```